# How to train a generalized extreme value model for anomaly detection?

Tags: modeling, model, fitting, extreme-value, anomaly-detection

### Background

I am building an anomaly detection solution. So far I used the simple z-score (#std from mean) approach. The latter implicitly assumes an underlying stationary Gaussian model. However, the data is very sparse and spiky so that model is not very valid and many false positives occur.

### The idea

I thought instead to use Generalized Extreme Value theorem according to all extreme values are distributed similarly. I found [this paper](http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2012/posters/An%20Extreme%20Value%20Theory%20Approach.pdf) which discusses a research project in line with my idea.

### The problem: how to fit the model?

However, I wonder how can this model be train as the fitting should take place on past extreme values. Should I bootstrap re-sample a max operation on past samples. If so, how large should be each sample? Should I ignore zero values?

### Example data

Enclosed is an image to illustrate the type of signals I am dealing with (red=train, green=test, arbitrary 70% split). A gaussian model would predict the green part to be anomouls as the std and mean of the red part is small (many zeros).

[image]

Comment: well, the rational appears in the linked paper: > ... "modeling the tail region of the distribution where anomalies occur"

Comment: OK, interesting. However I do not get what do you mean by using bootstraping in here? Your training data should be hourly/daily/weekly/yearly maximums or minimums (depending on your data and problem specification).

Comment: I meant computing the maximum on bootstrap samples of the past as an estimation of how does the maximum is distributed (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)  for details)

Comment: But your maximums are distributed according to EVD why parallel to using parametric distribution you want to use non-parametric bootstrap distribution? (and how do you want to use it?)

Comment: The idea is to fit a parametric distribution so one can compute the tail probability and decide if a new observable is an anomaly.